# Parameterize SQL query

Tags: c#, .net, sql, t-sql, ado.net

Many posts about Parameters in SQL with C# but I am still missing something. I am not getting an error message but no data is inserted. What is missing? I have text boxes named fname, lname, address, city, state and zip.

```
 private void enter_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string first, last, addy, city1, stat, zippy;
    first = fname.Text; 
    SqlParameter firstparam;
    firstparam = new SqlParameter();
    firstparam.ParameterName = "@first";
    firstparam.Value = first;
    last = lname.Text;
    SqlParameter lastparam;
    lastparam = new SqlParameter();
    lastparam.ParameterName = "@last";
    lastparam.Value = last;
    addy = address.Text;
    SqlParameter addressparam;
    addressparam = new SqlParameter();
    addressparam.ParameterName = "@addy";
    addressparam.Value = addy;
    city1 = city.Text;
    SqlParameter cityparam;
    cityparam = new SqlParameter();
    cityparam.ParameterName = "@city1";
    cityparam.Value = city1;
    stat = state.Text;
    SqlParameter stateparam;
    stateparam = new SqlParameter();
    stateparam.ParameterName = "@stat";
    stateparam.Value = stat;
    zippy = zip.Text;
    SqlParameter zipparam;
    zipparam = new SqlParameter();
    zipparam.ParameterName = "@zippy";
    zipparam.Value = zippy;

    try
    {
        Validate(fname);
        Validate(lname);
        Validate(city);
        Validate(state);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.ToString(), ex);
    }

    try
    {
        exValidate(address);
    }
    catch (Exception ex1)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex1.ToString(), ex1);
    }

    try
    {
        numValidate(zip);
    }
    catch (Exception ex2)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex2.ToString(), ex2);
    }


    string connection = "Data Source=TX-MANAGER;Initial Catalog=Contacts;Integrated Security=True";
    var sqlstring = string.Format("INSERT INTO Contacts ([First] ,[Last] ,[Address] ,[City] ,[State],[ZIP]) VALUES {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5})", @first, @last, @addy, @city1, @stat, @zippy);
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
    comm.CommandText = sqlstring;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        //SqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
        //comm.Transaction = trans;
        comm.Parameters.Add("@first", SqlDbType.Text);
        comm.Parameters.Add("@last", SqlDbType.Text);
        comm.Parameters.Add("@addy", SqlDbType.Text);
        comm.Parameters.Add("@city1", SqlDbType.Text);
        comm.Parameters.Add("@stat", SqlDbType.Text);
        comm.Parameters.Add("@zippy", SqlDbType.SmallInt);
    }
    catch (Exception commex)
    {
        throw new Exception(commex.ToString(), commex);
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

So I changed to this and still nothing happens.

```
     string connection = "Data Source=TX-MANAGER;Initial Catalog=Contacts;Integrated Security=True";
        var sqlstring = string.Format("INSERT INTO Contacts ([First] ,[Last] ,[Address] ,[City] ,[State],[ZIP]) VALUES {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5})", @first, @last, @addy, @city1, @stat, @zippy);
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
        SqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
        comm.CommandText = sqlstring;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            //SqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
            //comm.Transaction = trans;
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first", first);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last", last);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addy", addy);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city1", city1);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat", stat);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zippy", zippy);
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Your connection will not be closed in case of an exception since you're rethrowing the exception in the catch-clause and the `conn.Close()` is outside of the (not existing) finally-block. Use `using-statement` instead.

Answer (score 6):

You forgot to execute the command ;)

EDIT: you also didn't use the parameters that you created at the beginning of the method.

```
    ...
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        //SqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
        //comm.Transaction = trans;
        comm.Parameters.Add(firstparam);
        comm.Parameters.Add(lastparam);
        comm.Parameters.Add(addressparam);
        comm.Parameters.Add(cityparam);
        comm.Parameters.Add(stateparam);
        comm.Parameters.Add(zipparam);

        // This is what you forgot:
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    ...
```

BTW, don't do things like that:

```
    catch (Exception ex1)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex1.ToString(), ex1);
    }
```

It's useless, it just adds a new level of exception without adding anything useful. Just let the exception bubble up the stack until it reaches a catch block that actually does something useful.

Comment: Also, all his SqlParameters (firstparam, lastparam, etc ...) are not linked to the SqlCommand (comm) SqlParameterCollection

Comment: I think you're not correct: take a look, parameters added have no value. Parameters with values wasn't added.

Comment: oK. The code had a lot of flaws in itself. The embedded SQL statement itself is/was not correct. @GarethD pointed it out in his answer.

Answer (score 5):

The key issues in the provided sample are:

- The definition of the `sqlstring` should have the parameter definitions in the string
- The Call Stack is being reset when the error is thrown by creating a new error object
- The `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` object are not begin disposed correctly (for example, the `conn.Close()` call is not part of the `Finally` section of the exception handler.
- The `Value` of the `SqlParameters` are not being set
- The `Execute` xx method on the `SqlCommand` object is not begin called
- String Values are stored in a `varchar` type, not `Text`. Text is the deprecated SQL Server datatype to store blob.

I would Refactor the code as follows:

```
     private void enter_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        var first = fname.Text; 
        var last = lname.Text;
        var addy = address.Text;
        var city1 = city.Text;
        var stat = state.Text;
        var zippy = zip.Text;

        Validate(fname);
        Validate(lname);
        Validate(city);
        Validate(state);
        exValidate(address);
        numValidate(zip);

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TX-MANAGER;Initial Catalog=Contacts;Integrated Security=True"))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Contacts ([First], [Last], [Address], [City], [State], [ZIP]) VALUES (@first, @last, @addy, @city1, @stat, @zippy)", conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(
                new[]
                    {
                        new SqlParameter(@"first", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = first,
                        new SqlParameter(@"last", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = last,
                        new SqlParameter(@"addy", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = addy,
                        new SqlParameter(@"city1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = city1,
                        new SqlParameter(@"state", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stat,
                        new SqlParameter(@"zippy", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = zippy
                    });
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

*Note: I prefer supplying the datatype of parameters since SqlCE does not always work correctly when no type is supplied.*

Comment: it says it can't accept strings. the var first, last, etc. is getting set as a string but the sql string is being set using @first etc. instead of the values before the parameters.addRange(); I need to set the values first for the SqlParameters so when the SQL string is set, it is set using the SqlParameter.Values right? I can't just move the AddRange though because then the SqlCommand isn't initialized which throws errors at every command call before its initialized.

Comment: I added the missing brackets in the sql string

Comment: Also, the datatypes should be `Varchar`, not `text`

Comment: in the array I ended up creating a sqlParameter array and assigning each index like this: 
           sqlparam[0] = new SqlParameter(@"first", SqlDbType.Text);
           sqlparam[0].Value = first;

This worked to assign the values in the array and then called:
        comm.Parameters.AddRange(sqlparam);

Answer (score 3):

This will be much shorter:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Contacts ([First], [Last], [Address], [City], [State], [ZIP]) VALUES (@first, @last, @address, @city, @state, @zip)";

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first", first);
    // or
    // command.Parameters.Add("@first", SqlDbType.Type).Value = first;
    // ...

    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

---

But first of all here's what you missed:

```
comm.Parameters.Add(firstparam);
// instead of
// comm.Parameters.Add("@first", SqlDbType.Text);
```

and

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: So I changed to this and still nothing happens.

Comment: @marcmiller2007: Verify again that you set value to a parameters, and add it to the command. Then that you execute command. Also check connection string.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of going about it. One of the ways is to replace the lines in the try block with:

```
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first", first);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last", last);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addy", addy);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city1", city1);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat", stat);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zippy", zippy);
```

If you do that, you dont need all the **SqlParameter** initializations

And you obviously need to execute the command:

```
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you are not executing the command, you'll need to call `comm.ExecuteNonQuery();`, secondly your SQL string will be wrong. This line:

```
var sqlstring = string.Format("INSERT INTO Contacts ([First] ,[Last] ,[Address] ,[City],
[State],[ZIP]) VALUES {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5})", @first, @last, @addy, @city1, 
@stat, @zippy)
```

Can just be:

```
var sqlstring = "INSERT INTO Contacts ([First] ,[Last] ,[Address] ,[City] ,[State],[ZIP]) 
                 VALUES (@first, @last, @addy, @city1, @stat, @zippy)";
```

Thridly you are not actually adding your parameters to your command. You create a parameter like so:

```
SqlParameter zipparam;
zipparam = new SqlParameter();
zipparam.ParameterName = "@zippy";
zipparam.Value = zippy;
```

But you are adding this:

```
comm.Parameters.Add("@zippy", SqlDbType.SmallInt);
```

with no reference to `zipparam`. This means that the value `zippy` is never actually added to the command. You could do this all in one line using:

```
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@Zippy, SqlDbType.SmallInt)).Value = zippy;
```

Comment: You can write just `comm.Parameters.Add("@Zippy", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = zippy`;