# SQL Server connections in ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have created a web application with `asp.net`, roughly `100 users` are using it.

However from time to time people are getting the error message that the connection is still open. Indicating that it was not closed properly.

It appears on random places, not one specific place and no other errors before it.

I know that when I have a bug in the application and it crashes without me gracefully dealing with the error the connection remains open as well and basically everyone will crash because of it. This made me think that everyone uses the same connection object, is it possible that 2 users might have the perfect timing and invoke a function using a `DB connection` at the same time causing the error? Is there a way to make sure everyone uses their own connection objects, like put it in their session or something?

I hope you can understand what I mean, I don't think posting any of my code will help since it happens on random places within my project.

They are connection to a `SQL Server` using `System.Data.SqlClient`.

Find below the function which generates the error. This function is called by the Page_Load, nothing is before it.

```
public static SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Server00\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=r2;Integrated Security=true;Connect Timeout=0");

private void populateGameDrop()
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        drop_game.Items.Clear();

        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        Access ac = (Access)Session["Access"];
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from dbo.Games where " + ac.GameQuery;

        SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (r.Read())
        {
            drop_game.Items.Add(new ListItem(r["name"].ToString(), r["Abbr"].ToString()));
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        conn.Close();
        Log.Error(exc.ToString());
        Session["Error"] = exc.ToString();
        Response.Redirect("~/YouBrokeIt.aspx");
    }

    populateServers();
    SetSplitScreen();
}
```

Comment: I _think_ it is a good practice to open and close the connection on a per request basis. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585478/one-dbcontext-per-web-request-why/10588594#10588594) is based on Entity Framework's `DbContext` but I think it will apply to plain ADO, too.

Comment: Sorry, but without being able to **pinpoint** what code snippet causes these problems, this question is really waaay too broad. You'll need to do some more research on your own first, to be able to tell us *what* code is causing the issues

Comment: Add some code of how you are accessing the `DB` are you using `using` staments?

Comment: Basic suggestion is: create `SqlConnection` objects as late as possible - preferable immediately before creating an `SqlCommand` object that uses it, and wrap both of them in `using` statements. The only thing you should aim to be sharing around is the connection *string*.

Comment: @marc_s  I added the code where the exception comes from.

Comment: `static SqlConnection` shouldn't be static, it should be created inside a using stement

Comment: See @Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment - **don't** use `static` connections, create them as late as possible in a `using() { ... }` block. Set up command locally, too - in a `using() { ... }` block as well. Open connection, execute your command (or iterate over your reader), close connection as fast as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to share `SqlConnection` objects.

Try this instead:

```
private static string connString = "Data Source=Server00\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=r2;Integrated Security=true;Connect Timeout=0";
private void populateGameDrop()
{
    try
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            drop_game.Items.Clear();
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                Access ac = (Access)Session["Access"];
                //TODO
                //TODO - Introduce parameters to avoid SQL Injection risk
                //TODO
                cmd.CommandText = "Select name,Abbr from dbo.Games where " + ac.GameQuery;
                using(SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (r.Read())
                    {
                        drop_game.Items.Add(new ListItem(r["name"].ToString(),
                                            r["Abbr"].ToString()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Log.Error(exc.ToString());
        Session["Error"] = exc.ToString();
        Response.Redirect("~/YouBrokeIt.aspx");
    }
    populateServers();
    SetSplitScreen();
}
```

Behind the scenes, .NET uses a concept called [connection pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx) so that the actual number of *real* connections to SQL Server are minimized. But `SqlConnection` objects aren't designed to be shared by multiple threads.

Comment: You should *also* put your `SqlDataReader` into a `using() { .... }` block (if you're already doing it for `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` ....) - and you should also **parametrize** the query to avoid SQL injection

Comment: I see :O  This is very enlightening really.. Looks like ill be doing a lot of editting to my project.  as for the parameter suggestion, have been doing it on other queries, but this is bassicly a static query. No user input. Just the where is variable on earlier done functions.

Answer (score 1):

Don't place your database code directly in your ASPX pages. Creating an extra layer (i.e. DAL) allows you to test the DB methods without using the page.

Try something like this.

```
//Don't embed database logic directly in the aspx files
public class GamesProvider
{        
    //Put the ConnectionString in you configuration file
    private string ConnectionString
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GameDB"].ConnectionString; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Game> LoadGames(string x, string y)
    {
        var games = new List<Game>();

        const string queryString = "select name, Abbr from dbo.Games where x = @x and y = @y";

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", x);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@y", y);
            using (var dateReader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dateReader.Read())
                {
                    var game = new Game
                    {
                        Name = dateReader["name"].ToString(),
                        Abbr = dateReader["Abbr"].ToString(),
                    };
                    games.Add(game);
                }
            }
        }

        return games;
    }
}

//Use types
public class Game
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Abbr { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `SQL` connections shouldn't be static, use the following to create them

```
var connectionString = "YOUR CONNECTION STRING";
var queryString = "SQL QUERY";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
using (SqlDataReader dateReader = command.ExecuteReader()) {

}
```

**VERY IMPORTANT**

You should use parameterised `SQL` your code is open to `SQL` injection attacks.

please see [Parameterize SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898737/parameterize-sql-query)

Comment: You should really use `using() { .... }` blocks for `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader`

Comment: @marc_s good point I've updated my answer