# Additional information: Login failed for user ''. SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, ssrs-2012

I've been stock in this problem:

[image]

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim MyConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Server=DESKTOP-I0N45MV\SQL2012;Database=user;uid=;pwd=")
    Dim MyDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim MyDataAdapter1 As New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim Result As String
    Dim Result1 As String

    Private Sub login_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles login.Click
        MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand()
        MyDataAdapter1.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand()

        MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection = MyConnection
        MyDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.Connection = MyConnection
        MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "Select Username From users WHERE Username ='" & user_.Text & "'"
        MyDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.CommandText = "Select Password From users WHERE Password ='" & pass_.Text & "'"
        MyConnection.Open()
        Result = MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteScalar()
        Result1 = MyDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.ExecuteScalar()
        MyConnection.Close()
```

Comment: your connectionstring is not proper

Comment: what do you mean>

Comment: can you show your connection string which communicate between database and application

Comment: i edit my post.ccc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly **do not** ever use this:
`MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username ='" & user_.Text & "'"` since it will let your code be injectable by SQL injection, use a [stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260952/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-within-c-sharp-program) or [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898737/parameterize-sql-query) instead.

Secondly I don't understand why you would use two queries. 
Can't you do it with just one like `SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username = 'foo' AND Password = 'bar'` and then just use the result of this query?

Thirdly I would recommend that you pass the connection string as a parameter to your project. If you are coding a `WinForms` project, you can access it like this : `Dim connection As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.connectionString)`

And lastly since that's what you asked, your connection string should look like 
`Server=YourServerName;Database=YourDBName;Trusted_Connection=True;`.
If you use Windows Authentication on your SQL Server, it should look remotely like this `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;`, if you are using username and password to authenticate.

Comment: @hotchongas If that answer helped you with your problem either upvote (arrow up) or accept (check) it.