# How to pass in a variable for a sql insert command

Tags: c#, sql-server-express

I have a string that I want to insert into a column of a table using a sql command. If I have

```
string someText = 'onetwothreetest';
clsDB.ExecuteSQL("INSERT INTO tbl_SOMETABLE (SOMECOLUMN) VALUES (????)")
```

How would I put the string, someText, into the ???? without it giving me an error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
 string someText = 'onetwothreetest';
 clsDB.ExecuteSQL($"INSERT INTO tbl_SOMETABLE (SOMECOLUMN) VALUES ({someText})")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this post [Parameterize SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898737/parameterize-sql-query)

You need to create a Command Object and add Specify SQL, Parameters

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Contacts ([First], [Last], [Address], [City], [State], [ZIP]) VALUES (@first, @last, @address, @city, @state, @zip)";

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first", first);
    // or
    // command.Parameters.Add("@first", SqlDbType.Type).Value = first;
    // ...

    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: ::thumbsup:: thanks